# MySQL workbench, Can't create table error#1050

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[with "drop table if exists student"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mabKD.jpg)

[without "drop table if exists student"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiViE.jpg)

So,I connected the database to amazon rds.
I want to find the way to avoid the error without using "drop and flush".
I've spent few days to find the solution, but i haven't found any.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please add code (queries) as text not as  link to an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student`.

For the whole mysql `create table` Syntax look at the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)